# Replacing implausible values by condition in the entire data frame

Tags: r, conditional-statements

This is an example of my data. Everything is numeric.

```
df <- structure(list(Temp1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.7, 0.3, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 
0, 0.1, 0, 6553.1, 0.2, 0.2, 6553.4, 6553.5, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.6, 
0.9, 0.7), Temp2 = c(NA, NA, 17.5, 17.1, 17.1, 16.9, 16.7, 1004.6, 
17.6, 16.8, 16.3, 16.7, 17, 16.1, 16.1, 16.2, 16.1, 16.7, 16.7, 
17.1, 16.2, 17.1, 17.2), Temp3 = c(NA, 18.2, 17.8, 17.9, 17.9, 
18, 17.7, 17.4, 17.9, 17.7, 17.8, 17.2, 17.8, 17.3, 17.4, NA, 
NA, NA, 17.6, 17.8, 17.2, 17.8, 17.7), Temp4 = c(6553.4, 0.1, 
0.6, 0.9, 0.2, 6553.3, 0.1, 0, 6553.5, 6553.4, 0.4, 0.2, 6553.2, 
0.2, 0.1, 6553.4, 6553.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1.1, 1, 1.2, 1.1)), .Names = c("Temp1", 
"Temp2", "Temp3", "Temp4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-23L))
```

I want to replace all values larger than 40 by NA. 
I know how to replace one specific value, say 40:

```
df[df==40] <- NA
```

but I don't know how to correctly place the condition (>40) in that code. I've read other posts which use `lapply`, but I never seem to get it right.
I think I get the references wrong, if using `lapply` is a useful approach to my task.

Comment: just change `==` to `>`. `df[df>40] <- NA`.

Comment: @Hack-R thank you...now I feel a little stupid. It's so obvious. But one can always make things more difficult than they are. I better keep practicing.

Comment: Or use `is.na(df) <- df > 40`